Setting Woocommerce shipping method cost conditionally
I am about to set one shipping method cost to zero if products in cart costs more than 99.99 (incl. taxes), source code found here:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs_based_on_products_cost', 20, 2 );

function custom_shipping_costs_based_on_products_cost( $rates, $package ) {
    
    $products_amount = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
    $taxes_amount = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_tax();
    $total = $products_amount + $taxes_amount;

    if ($total > 99.98) {
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            if( $rate->method_id == 'alg_wc_shipping:198'){
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}

Code doesn't work, unfortunatelly, and I can't find out why. The part where I'm counting $total works fine, it's tested tested. Method ID is found in cart html code:
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_alg_wc_shipping198" value="alg_wc_shipping:198" class="shipping_method" checked="checked">

I also tried to remove condition and just change cost, also does nothing.

Sorry, but the linked code works fine for shipping methods, so please stop saying that the code doesn't work. To target a shipping rate ID, simply use the $rate_key argument, which is the shipping rate ID.

@LoicTheAztec Intersting, I just tried to change to method_id and it didn't work. Could it be because this method runs instances?

Maybe because it's about shipping methods from a third party plugin, that doesn't really respect WooCommerce shipping data structure. Normally the shipping rate ID is always also set as index in the rates data array. For sure, you can also get it from the rate id property.

Found it!
$rate->method_id should be changed to $rate->id. Here's a full code, updated for multiple methods:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs_based_on_products_cost', 20, 2 );

function custom_shipping_costs_based_on_products_cost( $rates, $package ) {
    
    $products_amount = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
    $taxes_amount = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_tax();
    $total = $products_amount + $taxes_amount;

    $free_methods = [
        'alg_wc_shipping:198',
        'alg_wc_shipping:222',
        'alg_wc_shipping:217',
        'alg_wc_shipping:219',
        'alg_wc_shipping:207',
        'alg_wc_shipping:212',
        'alg_wc_shipping:221',
    ];

    if ($total > 99.98) {
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            if (in_array($rate->id, $free_methods)) {
                $label = $rates[$rate_key]->label . ': бесплатно';
                $rates[$rate_key]->label = $label;
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0;
                if ( has_taxes ) {
                    $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}

